# Any readings/books recommended for a beginner mobile Qt developers?

Tags: qt, mobile, reference

I'm quite new to this mobile development. I just download the Qt SDK from the Nokia web site.

My background is C,C++ and I am not very familiar with the visual/IDE kind of stuff. Normally I do things using the console and the vi editor, etc. I have been spending almost 10 years of development mainly on web applications (PHP/Python/Flex/[ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript)/JavaScript/C/etc).

I am interested in jumping into this new wagon, of applications for mobiles. I need some guide to start with, any references such online documents/readings/examples or books for a starter like me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a official Qt book [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160). There are also other good [books](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/books) you can check out. You can find one that best suits your needs, given the background you came from and the knowledge you possess.

This would be a good [site](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/getting-started/getting-started) if you want to get started right away.

Documentation sites:

- http://doc.trolltech.com/
- http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Documentation/

Comment: I would upvote this answer by +10 !!